# Spacing on the right and bottom of the web-page when viewed in mobile version

Tags: html, css, web, space

I want an image to fit to screen, whether the screen size of big or small (phone, tablet, PC) and have no spaces either below or on the right.

My webpage looks fine when viewed in PC, as shown below:

[image]

However, when I inspect this same page as a mobile version, there is a blank space on the right and bottom of the page, as shown below:

[image]

After doing some digging in StackOverflow, I made a modification to '.carousel-inner { margin: auto!important }, but nothing is happening.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="J.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>J[a]son</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class = "logo">
            <h4>J[a]son</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CODING</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class= "burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">-->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-75" src="Photos/carousel.JPG" alt="First slide">
            <p>November, 2019. Seattle, USA.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-75" src="Photos/statute.JPG" alt="Second slide">
            <p>June, 2020. Kelowna, BC.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
           <!--<p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>-->
    <div class ="bottom">
      <div class = "logos">
        <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" target="_blank" class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black !important; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

nav {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    /*font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    background-color: black;
    color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*padding: 5px 5px;*/
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 45%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-control-prev {
        padding-top: 5em;
    }

    .carousel-control-next {
        padding-top: 5em;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        padding-top: 6em;
    }
    
    .logos { 
        padding-bottom: 0em;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png
}

.main_car_wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 6em;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity :1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);

}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    /*display: block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: rgb(221, 215, 215);
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 40px;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover{
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;   
}

li:hover ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}

li:hover a {
    background: rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background: rgb(19, 18, 18);
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: auto; 
}

.logos {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
}

.logos a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.logos a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.carousel-inner p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto!important;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50vw;
    max-height: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

/*.carousel-item {
    height: 300px
}*/

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

JS

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if(link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = ''
      } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.2s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
  //Animate Links
  
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: Just scroll to that section, open your elements panel and hover over all the section until you find the one that is too wide, then give it a `max-width` of 100% or something?

Comment: I tried right now and the right spacing seems to be an issue with top navigation bar. I tried max-width but seems to be not working..